# How does Kotlin store the data for a list?

Tags: kotlin, storage

I'd like to know how Kotlin stores data in a list. I've  read the source code of both the function `listOf` and the interface `List`, but I haven't been able to find where the data is stored. For example `val list = listOf(1,2,3)`. What kind of storage is used to store the three numbers?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: It depends on specific `List` implementation. The call of `listOf` in Kotlin results to `ArrayList` instance, the most typical `List` implementation  in both Kotlin and Java. `ArrayList` is located at `java.util.Arrays`, so feel free to browse its source code.

Comment: As Nikolai says, `List` is an interface, designed to allow many different types of implementation.  Many use an array of references, but others use a linked list, or tree, or are a view onto a more complex data structure (such as an ordered set or tree).  You could even write one that stores its info in a file, or on a network!  Of course, each of those has implications for performance characteristics, memory usage, &c — but those are issues for whoever _creates_ it, and in general **code _using_ the list should be able to work with any implementation** without making any assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the call chain, `listOf(vararg elements: T)` on JVM calls [`Arrays.asList(elements)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)), which looks like:

```java
    public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
        return new ArrayList<>(a);
    }
```

This is not the commonly used Java ArrayList, but rather a private class with the same name. But just like the public ArrayList, the items are stored in a backing Object Array. In this case, the `vararg` Object array is used directly as the backing array, so there is no redundant copying or allocating. The source code can be viewed [here](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java#L2834).

Comment: Thank you very much. I forgot that kotlin code is translated to java, which I don't know.